# Fixing 500 (Internal Server Error) while calling cross domain AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I have web simple .NET web service and trying to call it form Java Script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>



</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function ss() {

                var webserUrl = "http://localhost/WebService.asmx";
                var soapRequest =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
  <soap:Body> \
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
      <x>int</x> \
      <y>int</y> \
    </Add> \
  </soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: webserUrl,
                    contentType: "text/xml",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapRequest,
                    success: SuccessOccur,
                    error: ErrorOccur
                });

        };
        function SuccessOccur(data, status, req) {
            if (status == "success")
                alert("OK "+req.responseText);
        }
        function ErrorOccur(data, status, req) {
            alert("ERR "+req.responseText + " " + status);
        }
    </script>
    <form>
    <input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="ss()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Service :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public WebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }


}
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>

        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />

      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Where I should look for problem - server side or client one?
If server side where I should look for problem? Log files `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` not are not looking very informative.

Comment: try this var webserUrl = "http://localhost/WebService.asmx/yourmethodname";

Comment: inspect the body of the response, you have at least two issue in your code, you're missing soap headers and correct values for `x` and `y`